# Initialize Firebase references in two separate files in the new API

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have upgraded to the new API and don't know how to initialize Firebase references in two separate files:

```
    /* CASE 1 */
    // 1st file
    var config = {/* ...  */};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

    // 2nd file - initialize again
    var config = {/* ...  */};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

> RESULT: bundle.js:535 Uncaught Error: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists.

```
    /* CASE 2 */
    // 1st file
    var config = {/* ...  */};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

    // 2nd file - don't initialize
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

> RESULT: bundle.js:529 Uncaught Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp().

Before the new API I just called

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
```

in each file, and it worked okay.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is an issue I ran into as well upgrading to the new version of Firebase.  You might want two separate firebase apps initialized, like explained in other answers, but I just wanted to use the refs in two different locations in my app and I was getting the same error.

What you need to do for this situation is to create a firebase module for your app that only initializes firebase once, then you import or require it elsewhere in your app.

This is pretty simple, here is mine:  modules/firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "some-api-key",
  authDomain: "some-app.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://some-app.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "some-app.appspot.com",
};

var FbApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
module.exports.FBApp = FbApp.database(); //this doesnt have to be database only
```

And then elsewhere in your application you simply:

```
import FBApp from '/your/module/location'
var messagesRef = FBApp.ref("messages/");
```

Comment: importing like that did not work for me. I had to do `const firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database")`. I'm using firebase v3.0.5. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: well this example is using ES6 modules, which if you're building an app in the browser you will need to use something like babel.  Using require is  fine too, its up to you which type of modules you wish to use in your app.  I figure for longevity sake ES6 modules is probably the way to go for examples, I can make a require example too if you think that would be helpful, but its very similar.

Comment: I am facing this same issue and not sure if I understand the answer correctly. Is  the `FbApp` in `var FbApp` in the first snippet supposed to be the same thing as `Firebase` in `import Firebase` in the second?

Comment: @lommaj I just tried again to give you the exact error, and it turns out it works just fine. I guess my error at the time was related to authentication utils having been moved to the instance of the app: `const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)`.

Comment: @kpg There is no exact equivalent to the old Firebase that you could import in v2. But if you use `FbApp.database().ref()` (as obtained in the answer) that is equivalent to the old `new Firebase(yourFirebaseRootUrl)`, it gives you the root ref of the database.

Comment: @kpg, essentially when you import firebase in the second location (or as many other locations as you need in your app) you would be referencing the one initialized app (FBApp) instead of instantiating an entirely new firebase database ref like you would in previous versions of firebase.

Comment: @lommaj I understand the principle. My question is about the code in your answer. What I see is that your modules/firebase.js exports something called `FbApp`, but 'elsewhere in your application' you are importing `Firebase`.

Comment: oh you are absolutely right, I will edit that, I misunderstood the comment.

Comment: @lommaj what does ` FBApp.ref("messages/") ` mean in the last line ?

Comment: I was just adding an example of getting a real time database reference location from the imported module to show that its actually a usable firebase instance.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 31):

You need to name your different instances (Apps as Firebase calls them); by default you're working with the `[DEFAULT]` App, because that's the most common use case, but when you need to work with multiple Apps then you have to add a name when initialising:

```
// Intialize the "[DEFAULT]" App
var mainApp = firebase.intializeApp({ ... });

// Intialize a "Secondary" App
var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp({ ... }, "Secondary");
...
mainApp.database().ref("path/to/data").set(value);
secondaryApp.database().ref("path/to/data").set(anotherValue);
```

You can find a more example scenarios in the updated [Initialize multiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#initialize_multiple_apps) section of the Add Firebase to your JavaScript Project guide.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are trying to initialize two different firebase applications, but the question said he was trying to initialize it in two different files, not two different applications.  You would not want to initialize the same app twice, so I think my answer above is correct for this particular question.

Comment: But if I want to have one app, unauthenticated, at /index.html, and another, authenticated, say at /providers/index.html, and publish the latter to users as the landing url, how would I ensure initialization ?  My first thought is to test mainApp for existence in both places?  Any thoughts from anyone?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have the control over where Firebase will be instantiated, you can do something like this:

```
 try {
    let firApp = firebase.app(applicationName);
    return firApp;
  } catch (error) {
    return firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(firebaseCredentials),
      databaseURL: firebaseUrl
    }, applicationName);
  }
```

Firebase will try to get the application, if it doesn't exist, then you can initialize it freely.

Comment: Best solution to this issue ever.. even if I don't fully understand why this keep happening as I'd expect to have a clean state on each function execution, and no a "random" repercussion from previous execution!

Comment: Appreciate this answer; gave me the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I made the mistake by importing like this.

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'key',
  authDomain: 'domain',
  databaseURL: 'url',
  storageBucket: ''
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

This worked fine for a few days but when I tried to sign in with [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) my auth object was not changed. I had to refresh the page for it to update so I could make certain calls to the database which were protected by my own auth credentials rules.

```
 ".read": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.isAdmin === true || auth.isTeacher === true",
```

When I changed my imports to this it worked again.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'key',
  authDomain: 'domain',
  databaseURL: 'url',
  storageBucket: ''
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Then whenever I need to use Firebase in a certain module I import this(notice the import from firebase/app instead of firebase):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

And talk to certain services like so:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // Authenticated.
  } else {
    // Logged out.
  }
});

firebase.database().ref('myref').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  // do stuff with the snapshot
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To make multiple instances using `new firebase.initializeApp()`, you need a second parameter for the firebase constructor:

```
firebase.initializeApp( {}, "second parameter" );
```

Compare it to the old way to generate multiple instances where

```
new Firebase.Context()
```

is the second parameter:

```
new Firebase('', new Firebase.Context() );
```

Answer (score 0):

For a small fraction of the people here, this issue might be cause by trying to initialize fb admin on the same script that you used to initialize fb on the front end. If anybody is initializing firebase twice on the same script (once for admin and once for frontend), then you need initialize firebase admin in a different script than in front end, and do not import anything that is exported on the backend script on the frontend (and vise versa).