# Webpack "Uncaught Type Error" when importing Firebase module into standard Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to use a module to access a Firebase database in multiple locations within my Vue.js project.

I used the standard Vue.js boilerplate (`vue init webpack-simple [projectName]`) to get started.

I was able to pull data from the Firebase instance from a single Vue component. I've put all of the code in GitHub to save space here. This initial commit works fine: https://github.com/thoragio/webpack-vue-firebase-issue/commit/b5cee2152cf8cc48bda936ac61ea242c381e4a96

I then followed the instructions here to create the Firebase module: [Initialize Firebase references in two separate files in the new API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337080/initialize-firebase-references-in-two-separate-files-in-the-new-api)

Here are the changes I made according to the post above: https://github.com/thoragio/webpack-vue-firebase-issue/commit/66f776367aa723cc65690e3ac70de0c049ec961d

However, when I run it, I get the following error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__modules_firebase_js___default.a.child is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1042), <anonymous>:15:78)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:1042)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:660)
    at fn (build.js:84)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1360), <anonymous>:8:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:1360)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:660)
    at fn (build.js:84)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1035), <anonymous>:3:83)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:1035)`

I tried bumping `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` to their latest version, but the error persisted. Bumping changes are here: https://github.com/thoragio/webpack-vue-firebase-issue/commit/851869528979e7b4746624a389375c3f014d0bc4

I've been googling this for an hour now and can't make any headway, so I appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks.

I am new to Webpack so apologies in advance if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was PEBCAK.

I guess I was using outdated syntax. I changed:

`module.exports.FBApp = fbApp.database().ref()`

to:

`const FBApp = fbApp.database().ref()
export default FBApp`

It then worked.