# (Webpack failing to build?) Firebase DB in different levels of Vue components

Tags: firebase, webpack, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, web-component

I'm trying to set up a vue-fire app using single file Vue components.
I'm using the standard (full) Vue-cli Webpack template available on the official site.

I have firebase loaded in `App.vue` like this:

```
 let config = {
     ...
 };
 let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
 let db = app.database();
 let usersRef = db.ref('users');
```

...

```
export default {
     name: 'app',
     data () {
         return {
             login: {
                 email: '',
                 password: ''
             },
             newUser: {
                 email: '',
                 password: ''
             },
             showRegister: false
         }
     },
     firebase: {
               users: usersRef,
     },
     ...
}
```

I'm using Vue-router and my routes are set up like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import News from '@/components/News'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
      {
          path: '/',
          name: 'Home',
          component: Home
      },
      {
          path: '/news',
          name: 'News',
          component: News

      }
  ]
})
```

I would like to be able to access my Firebase app in the 'News' component.  The problem is that if I include the entire Firbase setup in the News.vue file, I get the error:

```
[DEFAULT]: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).
```

The [recommended solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337080/initialize-firebase-references-in-two-separate-files-in-the-new-api) is to export the initialized app's database in App.vue and import it in the child component.  So I add this to the bottom of my `App.vue` script:

```
 module.exports.FBApp = app.database();
```

And this to `News.vue`:

```
 import FBApp from '../App.vue'
 let usersRef = FBApp.ref('users')
```

But now I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__App_vue___default.a.ref is not a function
```

Does anyone know how to do this?  Surely it can't be too hard.

Comment: are you using vuefire?

Comment: @Ffloriel  Yes I am

Comment: @DavidJ. is this resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a db.js file like the following alongside app.vue.

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
  apiKey: 'xxxxx'
  authDomain: 'xxxxx'
  databaseURL: 'xxxxx'
  projectId: 'xxxxx'
  storageBucket: 'xxxxx'
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxx'
}
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)

const db = firebaseApp.database()

export default db
```

In your main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VueFire from 'vuefire'

// explicit installation required in module environments
Vue.use(VueFire)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

And now in any component, eg:

```
<template>
  <span>
    {{ news }}
  </span>  
</template>
<script>
import db from '../db'
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      users: [],
      sample: []
    }
  },
  firebase: function () {
    return {
      news: db.ref('news')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work but I'm getting a strange error when I run npm run build:
`ERROR in ./~/vue-fire/mixin.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib/fire' in '/home/david/projects/challenge/node_modules/vue-fire'
 @ ./~/vue-fire/mixin.js 7:11-32
 @ ./~/vue-fire/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js

  Build complete.
`

Comment: have you installed firebase. Also can you post your package.json

Comment: Also please post your app.vue and main.js

Comment: Your code was fine, I just stupidly replaced vuefire with vue-fire.  Thanks for the help, have 50 points!