# angularjs + angularfire script placement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

hope I can explain the issue I'm having as clearly as I possibly can.

So, if I place the following scripts in my index.html head:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.6/firebase.js"></script>

<script>firebase.initializeApp({
                apiKey: "AIzaSyAbyawNajCozBP1IgCdK8uVflV-tdp0TjI",
                authDomain: "ngbs-c469c.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://ngbs-c469c.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "ngbs-c469c",
                storageBucket: "ngbs-c469c.appspot.com"                        })</script>
```

It all works as expected.

However, instead of putting all my script src in the head I import them in a main.js file. So we would have:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

This also works fine.

My question is where should I place the `firebase.initializeApp({...})` in order for it to work the same as putting it in the head tag?

Answer (score 0):

The link below can be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase
In your code, you can access Firebase using:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
```

If you are using ES6 imports or TypeScript:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
var app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didnt quite answer my question. The problem is not accesing firebase, but in which js file should I put the script accesing firebase if I'm using an angular arhitecture. I can post the content of my index.js where I do all my imports if needed.

Comment: @TudorApostol 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337080/initialize-firebase-references-in-two-separate-files-in-the-new-api
This might help you.