# How to initialize 2 Firebases in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/JjXOgKL

```
 // Try commenting fill_func() out or..
    fill_func()
    // Try commenting pic_func() out or..
    pic_func()
    
    // However, initilializing 2 firebases cannot be executed
```

Your help will be appreciated. Please provide a codepen demo.

Comment: same questions:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337080/initialize-firebase-references-in-two-separate-files-in-the-new-api

Comment: that is python not javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize Firebase references in two separate files in the new API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337080/initialize-firebase-references-in-two-separate-files-in-the-new-api)